# First row for each 'OR' condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a query:

```
SELECT ID, Name, EventTime FROM table
    WHERE Name = 'value1' AND EventTime < timeValue1
       OR Name = 'value2' AND EventTime < timeValue2
       OR Name = 'value3' AND EventTime < timeValue3
       ...
ORDER BY EventTime DESC
```

Each condition `Name = ... AND EventTime < ...` can return multiple rows, but I need only the **first** row from each `OR` condition according to `ORDER BY` clause.

Is there any way to achieve this or any workaround?

Comment: first row based on **what order?**

Comment: @ZoharPeled based on `EventTime DESC` that means the row with Max `EventTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to me you are searching row_number()

```
  select * from (  SELECT ID, Name, EventTime
    , row_number() over(partition by Name order by  EventTime DESC) rn  FROM table
    WHERE Name = 'value1' AND EventTime < timeValue1
       OR Name = 'value2' AND EventTime < timeValue2
       OR Name = 'value3' AND EventTime < timeValue3
       ...
  ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;
WITH A
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [GROUP] ORDER BY 1) as RN
    FROM 
    (
            SELECT ID, Name, EventTime,  
            CASE WHEN Name = 'value1' AND EventTime < timeValue1 THEN '1'
                 WHEN Name = 'value2' AND EventTime < timeValue2 THEN '2'
                 WHEN Name = 'value3' AND EventTime < timeValue3 THEN '3'
                 WHEN Name = 'value3' AND EventTime < timeValue4 THEN '4'
                 --Could be more here
                 END as [Group]
            FROM table
    )
) 
SELECT * FROM A WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY EventTime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would approach this as:

```
SELECT ID, Name, EventTime
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY t.eventtime DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table t JOIN
           (VALUES ('value1', timevalue1), ('value2', timevalue2), ('value3', timevalue3)
           ) v(name, timevalue)
           ON t.name = v.name and t.eventtime < v.timevalue
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY EventTime DESC;
```

I much prefer using a derived table for such repetitive values, rather than embedding them in query logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT Top (1) ID, Name, EventTime FROM table
    WHERE Name = 'value1' AND EventTime < timeValue1
       OR Name = 'value2' AND EventTime < timeValue2
       OR Name = 'value3' AND EventTime < timeValue3
       ...
ORDER BY EventTime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as all your column names are the same you could use unions.

```
SELECT top 1 ID, Name, EventTime FROM table
WHERE Name = 'value1' AND EventTime < timeValue1
ORDER BY EventTime DESC
UNION
SELECT top 1 ID, Name, EventTime FROM table
WHERE 
    Name = 'value2' AND EventTime < timeValue2
ORDER BY EventTime DESC
UNION
SELECT top 1 ID, Name, EventTime FROM table
WHERE 
    Name = 'value3' AND EventTime < timeValue3
ORDER BY EventTime DESC
```

EDIT: had extra or statements, removed them.